# show that the given series (3/2-4/3)+(5/4-6/5)+.......is convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series

"show that the given series $(3/2-4/3)+(5/4-6/5)+....... $ is convergent. Give reason for obtaining different nature of the series before and after grouping the terms."           The nth term of this series is $(-1)^{n+1} \dfrac{n+2}{n+1}$. I approach by Leibnitz's test but this gives the series is divergent, please help me.

Comment: You may need to check the problem sheet again. The reason you fail in showing convergence is that this series diverges. Try proving that instead.

Comment: But i need showing convergent because question says show convergent.

Comment: I have done some correction of this question.

Comment: You don't show the series is convergent because the question says so. You show convergence if it **does** converge, otherwise it does not, no matter how badly one may want it to. Now, if the $n$'th term is $(-1)^{n+1}(n+2)\over n+1$, then the series diverges. If, however, the $n$'th term is understood as _the thing in brackets_, then it's another story (and another formula, BTW).

Comment: You may already have been told that if a term is of the form $\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(n+2)}{n+1}$, then the series diverges.
However, I think the expression in brackets corresponds to one term of the series. So for example, your first term is $\frac 32 - \frac 43 = \frac 16$, your second term is $\frac 54 - \frac 65 = \frac 1{20}$,  so your series is $\frac 16 + \frac{1}{20} + \ldots$. Please tell me if this is correct, then I can  tell you this series  is convergent, and prove it in an answer. But I need confirmation.

Comment: @ actoh.. i can't make the nth term of 6,20,42,72....

Comment: @actoh.. why you told  1/6+1/20+1/42+1/72 is convergent?

Comment: Because, for example, you may compare it with $1\over n^2$ which is known to be convergent. But still, you have to derive the n'th term first.

Comment: But i can't make nth term.

Comment: You already did, in a way. Now you split all those $(-1)^{n+1}(n+2)\over n+1$ into pairs and find the value of one such pair.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that your nth term is incorrect.

$$\frac{2n+1}{2n} - \frac{2n+2}{2n+1} $$
Will get you $(3/2 - 4/3)$ for $n=1$, $(5/4 - 6/5)$ for $n=2$ and so on.

Simplifying, this makes the nth term:
$$\frac{(2n+1)^2 - 2n(2n+2)}{2n(2n+1)} $$
$$=\frac{4n^2 + 4n + 1 - 4n^2 - 4n}{2n(2n+1)} $$
$$=\frac {1}{2n(2n+1)} $$

Now, $$\frac{1}{4n^2 + 2n} < \frac{1}{n^2}$$ for all natural numbers $n $, and it is well-known (and fairly straightforward to prove) that the sum of $\frac{1}{n^2} $ converges (to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ in fact), so that we can say the sum in question is bounded above by $\pi^2 /6$ and bounded below by $1/6$

With some clever manipulation, we can find the exact value.
Expanding $\frac{1}{2n(2n+1)} = \frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{2n+1} $:
$$1/2 - 1/3 + 1/4 - 1/5 +.... $$
$$ = -(-1/2 + 1/3 - 1/4 + 1/5 -...) $$
$$= 1 - (1 - 1/2 + 1/3 - 1/4 + 1/5 - ...) $$
The sum on the right is just the alternating harmonic series, which converges to $\ln(2)$ (which can be seen by using the Taylor expansion of $\ln(1+x)$). Therefore, the original sum converges to $1 - \ln(2)$.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the given series (without grouping terms) then the generic
term $a_n$ for stage $n$ is indeed: $a_n=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{n+2}{n+1}$ and hence the series do no converge since $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\ne 0$.

For the second part look at the solution of @infinitylord

Comment: yes I saw it... going to fix

Comment: This is incorrect. You only get the desired grouped terms for $n \ge 3$ where $n$ is odd. For example, expanding out $n=4$, you get $\frac{4}{3} - {5}{3}$, which is non-existent in the series. See my solution.

Comment: @infinitylord I've already looked at... I wanted just to see if there was a way to use telescoping... but maybe not

Comment: No I don't see any telescoping possibility... so canceling

Comment: I don't believe the exact value can be obtained by telescoping, but I have updated my answer to include the exact value by means of comparison with the alternating harmonic series.

Comment: @infinitylord That was the idea but I didn't recall about $\ln(1+x)$ series. Good occasion to revise ;-)